# Observance of the Passover - Timeline

Tags: passover

I wonder what the precise timeline of the observance of the Passover would look alike. The following chart shows a basic interpretation I have put together as a starting point. I would like to hear your qualified feedback / additions / corrections. Had the Passover consistently been observed during the Intertestamental period? When after 70 AD did the Jews / Christians start again to observe the Passover (in limited form without the temple)?

[image: Updated Passover Timeline]

Comment: For clarification - are you asking if the Passover was observed by individuals during the times indicated in red on your chart?  Or is your focus on the full Passover celebration from the temple in Jerusalem?  Since 70 A.D. Jews still keep Passover even though there is no temple.  Perhaps I'm a bit slow on the uptake, but your question might need clarification.

Comment: Passover is always collective and associated to a specific place (at least fom 1445 BC until 70AD). But yes, the last part of the question "in limited form without the temple" does give allowance to the decentralized and unbiblical form the Jews celebrate it today.

Comment: From a Christian perspective, we are the Temple of God (Jn 2:21, 1 Cor 6:19).  Where ever a Christian observes Passover is where God dwells (Deut 16:16).  So, after 30ad Christians have observed it continuously.  From a Jewish perspective, their synagogue replaced the Jerusalem temple.

Comment: It is unlikely they kept the Passover during the forty years of wandering in the wilderness. One of the requirements to participate was to be circumcised (Gen.12). As we know, the second generation was circumcised in the Promised Land by Joshua, after crossing the Jordan.

Comment: Circumcision related to the Passover was only mandatory for foreigners (see Exo. 12:48). Jews had to be circumcised for reasons not related to Passover . Jews did take the Passover in Egypt without previous circumcision. The Jews only mixed with foreigners once they entered Canaan and had been rather by themselves during the Exodus (with the exception of some wars and Moses marrying a Syrian woman although Cush was probably identical or adjacent to the area the Arameans ([Abram, Rebekah, Leah, Rachel] came from).

Comment: Therefore the Jews would have taken the Passover in their camps without circumcision, because there were no foreigners to be distinguished from. Numbers 9 also affirms a second Passover in the wilderness of Sinai.

Comment: I was referring to the time of wandering in the wilderness after leaving Mount Sinai.

Comment: All Israelites that kept the first Passover in Egypt were circumcised. Moses almost died on the way to Egypt because one of his sons was not (Ex.4).

Comment: Cush is in Africa.

Comment: ”...But no uncircumcised male may ever eat the Passover meal. This instruction applies to everyone, whether a native-born Israelite or a foreigner living among you.” (Ex.12:48-49)

Comment: The Greek name Αἰθιοπία (from Αἰθίοψ, Aithiops, "an Ethiopian") is a compound word, later explained as derived from the two Greek words, from αἴθω + ὤψ (aithō "I burn" + ōps "face")."

"Since the Greeks understood the term as "dark-faced", they divided the Ethiopians into two, those in Africa and THOSE TO THE EAST FROM EASTERN TURKEY to India."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopia#Etymology

"Cushan is from central or northern Syria, and is to be identified with a North Syrian ruler"
https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/cushan-rishathaim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hezekiah observed the Passover prior to Josiah.

> And Hezekiah sent to all Israel and Judah, and wrote letters also to Ephraim and Manasseh, that they should come to the house of the LORD at Jerusalem, to keep the passover unto the LORD God of Israel. 2 Chr 30:1

Initially, they kept it the 2nd month, and thereafter deemed to keep it in the 1st month.  Josiah then continues.

> Moreover Josiah kept a passover unto the LORD in Jerusalem: and they killed the passover on the fourteenth day of the first month. 2 Chr 35:1

Between Josiah and Ezra, the bible is silent, but tough to argue from silence.

To back up to the beginning, after the first Passover in Egypt, they kept it in the Wilderness.

> And Moses spake unto the children of Israel, that they should keep the passover. (Num 9:4)

They also observed it at first in the Promised Land under Joshua.

> And the children of Israel encamped in Gilgal, and kept the passover on the fourteenth day of the month at even in the plains of Jericho. Jos 5:10

Between Joshua and Hezekiah, the bible is silent.  More than likely, however, they were keeping Passover for couple hundred years before Christ walks the earth.

So, Egypt, Wilderness, Promised Land, Captivity (Hezekiah, Josiah), Restoration (Ezra), Christ all are signified by Passover.

Regarding 70AD Temple destruction, I mentioned this in the comments.

From a Christian perspective, we are the Temple of God (Jn 2:21, 1 Cor 6:19). Where ever a Christian observes Passover is where God dwells (Deut 16:16). So, after 30ad Christians have observed it continuously.

From a Jewish perspective after 70ad, their local synagogue replaced the Jerusalem temple.  I believe they observe it continously.

So, generally speaking, your timeline appears fairly accurate with the addition of Hezekiah.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the chart accordingly.